# Insert rows into excel range via formulae

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following range in column A :

```
01-Mar-12
01-Apr-12
01-May-12
01-Jun-12
01-Jul-12
01-Aug-12
01-Sep-12
01-Oct-12
01-Nov-12
01-Dec-12
01-Jan-13
01-Feb-13
01-Mar-13
01-Apr-13
01-May-13
01-Jun-13
01-Jul-13
01-Aug-13
01-Sep-13
```

In column B, I would like the same list of dates ( i.e. March 12 -> Sep 13), but I would like every August to be duplicated:

```
01-Mar-12
01-Apr-12
01-May-12
01-Jun-12
01-Jul-12
01-Aug-12
01-Aug-12
01-Sep-12
01-Oct-12
01-Nov-12
01-Dec-12
01-Jan-13
01-Feb-13
01-Mar-13
01-Apr-13
01-May-13
01-Jun-13
01-Jul-13
01-Aug-13
01-Aug-13
01-Sep-13
```

I can add as many columns in between as I like, but it must be done with formulae.

I'm having a little trouble figuring this out - any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A formula is not capable of inserting rows.

Copy ColumnA to ColumnB, insert a cell and shift down immediately under each `Aug` and in the blanks created enter:

```
=R[-1]C
```

Answer (score 0):

This formula works, assuming the values in column A are unique. Paste the formula into cell B3.

```
=IF(AND(MONTH(B2)=8,MONTH(B1)<>8),B2,INDEX(A:A,MATCH(B2,A:A,0)+1))
```

The current formula assumes that B1 and B2 are part of the list in column B. You'll have to manually fill in the values for B1 and B2 unless you change the formula a little.

What the formula does:

1. If B2 is August and B1 is not, then B3 copies the value of B2.
2. Otherwise B3 is the date in Column A found under the date B2.

You can then copy the formula into the remaining cells below B3.